# How to read data from a CSV file of two possible encodings?

Tags: csv, encoding

I want to read data from csv files with two possible encodings (UTF-8 and ISO-8859-15). I mean different files with different encodings. Not the same file with two encodings.
Now I can only read data correctly from a utf-8 encoding file. Can I just implement this by adding an extra option? For example . `encoding: 'ISO-8859-15'`

What i have:

```rb
def csv
   file = File.open(file.tempfile)
   CSV.open(file, csv_options)
end

private

def csv_options
{
   col_sep: ";",
   headers: true,
   return_headers: false,
   skip_blanks: true 
}
end
```

Comment: You as a programmer knows what encoding a particular string is. There is nothing in the (external) string itself which would reveal it's encoding. I think the closest you can do, is to read the file as a sequence of bytes, and then create strings out of it; even then, you will have to tell Ruby what encoding the string is supposed to be. However, having a file where different parts are using different encodings, is weird. We can't honestly call it a "text file" anymore. I would fix this at the place where the file is generated.

Comment: I have added the description

Comment: You can specify the encoding of a file when you open it via the built-in `open()` function's `encoding` argument — see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). After doing that, you can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module to read the data, it can handle all those options except "skip_blanks".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you know what encoding your file has, you can pass inside the CSV options i.e.

```
external_encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_15, 
internal_encoding: Encoding::UTF_8
```

(This would establish, that the file is ISO-8859-15, but you want the strings internally as UTF-8).

So the strategy is that you decided first (before opening the file), what encoding you want, and then use the appropriate option Hash.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good idea. But how can I find out the encoding of a file?

Comment: You ask the person who provided you the file. Encoding does not explain itself. For instance, a configuration file can come with it to explain the encoding, or you can take the approach used by text emails: The email-header is by default encoded in US-ASCII, and one of the headers states the encoding (by using ASCII encoding for the word denoting the actual encoding of the body). With this information, you know the encoding of the body.