# How to read data from a CSV file containing special characters of two encodings in a same file?

Tags: c#, utf-8, read.csv

I want to read data from CSV file containing a special characters with two possible encodings (UTF-8 and ANSI). I mean the same files with different encodings. If a file contains only UTF-8 encoded data using UTF8Encoding(true) while reading works fine. Similarly, If a file contains only ANSI encoded data using default encoding while reading works fine. But my file contains data encoded in both encoding.**How can I read it without messing up special characters??**

Image link attached shows a file in which line 1 is in UTF-8 encoding and line 2 is in ANSI encoding.

[image]

Here is how I created this file.

1. Open notepad++ and put characters ™ or ® with utf-8 encoding and save
2. Open that file in excel and Added special character ™ or ® and save

Here is my code:

```
private string _chunkLoaded(byte[] input,string fileEncoding)
{
    Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding(true); ;
    if (fileEncoding == "ANSI")
    {
        encoding = Encoding.Default;
    }
    var data = encoding.GetString(input, 0, input.Length);
}
```

Comment: You indicated that this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71204640/7733418 , which does have an accepted answer. Please explain the difference, it might help making your own question clearer.

Comment: In this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204640/how-to-read-data-from-a-csv-file-of-two-possible-encodings it is reading two different csv  files with different encodings. But I have to read only one file with which contains two differenct Encoding.

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid having a file with mixed encoding? It sounds entirely corrupt and evil. If you must have it, do you know in advance which line numbers are in which encoding? And the newline convention of the file, maybe? If you do not know what lines are what, how can you decide it? There are octet sequences that are valid in both UTF-8 and "ANSI".

Comment: Remark: If with Notepad++ you create a file with `UTF-8-BOM` (instead of just `UTF-8`), then you can likely make silly Excel behave better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JeppeStigNielsen .Creating files is in the hands of vendor. We have to accept and process file in any encoding they sent us . In this case vendors sent us a file  in UTF-8 format but inside characters were in mixed encoding as mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: No I don't know in advance which line numbers are in which encoding. In the sample file in screenshot if I changed encoding in notepad++ to ANSI then line 2 is correctly displayed and If I changed encoding to UTF-8 then line 1 is displayed correctly. This is how I new there were 2 encodings in the file. So is there any way to read those mixed encodings of a same file????

Comment: You would need to write your own decoder, I guess. But how would you determine what to do? Say, if you meet the two bytes `0xC3, 0xB3` in succession, it could be ANSI for `Ã³` (capital A with tilde, followed by cube symbol (raised figure 3)). But it could also be UTF-8 for `ó` (o with acute accent). So what would you do? Maybe it would depend on whether other bytes in the vicinity are also valid as UTF-8? It sounds like the data from your vendor is garbage.

Comment: Yes the vendor data is somehow garbage. But trying to fix even vendor sends data with mix encoding. Still searching for some way to solve it.